# localhost infinitely loading nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am starting to learn Node.js and as the first step I am deploying my server using `node.js`

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const { readFile } = require("fs/promises");

const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {

    readFile('./home.html', 'utf8', (err, html) => {
        if(err){
            response.status(500).send("Sorry, we are out of order");
        }

        response.send(html);
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`App available on http://localhost:3000`))
```

But the when i click that link, the localhost seems to be loading infintely.I have tried with different ports.I am using powershell for this and not a WSL.What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Did you try debugging with logging? It could be that the route is never called, it could be readFile failing silently for unknown reasons, it could be that you lack a `next` in your function handling the GET request and don't call `next` at all...

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals So i tried console logging after commenting the ```readFile``` code,but the server keeps on loading although output has been console logged in vscode terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `node` [`path`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-use-the-path-module/) `module`, and put your `html` file into **root directory**. It works like a charm.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
// const { readFile } = require("fs/promises");

const app = express();

// app.get("/", (request, response) => {
//   readFile("./home.html", "utf8", (err, html) => {
//     if (!err) {
//       response.status(500).send("Sorry, we are out of order");
//     }
//     response.send(html);
//   });
// });

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/home.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`App available on http://localhost:3000`));
```